# converting image from pixel array

Tags: java, image-processing

1. I am trying to convert a pixel matrix into an image but its not working. Can anyone help me? Below is the code. Here i have added a print statement to check if it is running or not, but its also not executing. can anyone help me here
2. This is the code which is giving problem.
3. This is the full code.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public final class Util {
    /**
     * Converts a java.awt.Image into an array of pixels
     */
    public static int[] convertToPixels(Image img) {
        int width = img.getWidth(null);

        int height = img.getHeight(null);
        int[] pixel = new int[width * height];

        PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, width, height, pixel, 0, width);
        try {
            pg.grabPixels();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error: Interrupted Waiting for Pixels");
        }
        if ((pg.getStatus() & ImageObserver.ABORT) != 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error: Image Fetch Aborted");
        }
        return pixel;
    }

    public static Image getImageFromArray(int[] pixels, int width, int height) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();
        raster.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixels);
        File output = new File("C:\\out.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
        System.out.print("written");
        return image;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int width, height;
        BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
        width = source.getWidth();
        height = source.getHeight();
        // Util obj = new Util();
        Util.getImageFromArray(convertToPixels(source), width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I have pasted the full code here. Output is not coming i.e. its not creating a file named out.png anywhere.

Comment: What is your main goal? Create Image from file?

Comment: yes, i wanted to try to convert a pixel array to an image and to write it @Nikolay

Comment: you don't need convert a file to a pixel array and then to an image - just do: `Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));`

Comment: @Nikolay i Know i can do this, but it was a part of bicubic interpolation, i wanted to write a code for bicubic interpolation without any third party library, so was testing by writing this code if it is possible to convert matrix to image. after converting an image to matrix i will apply bicubic operation on that matrix and then i will convert that resultant matrix into an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Image getImageFromArray(int[] pixels, int width, int height) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster(); //faster - no copy
    raster.setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, pixels); //instead of setPixels
    File output = new File("C:\\out.png");
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
    System.out.print("written");
    return image;
}
```